# Why is it "at upper left" as opposed to "on the upper left"?

Tags: prepositions, articles, definite-article

A photo in an article with a caption that reads:

> [image]
>   Law enforcement officers during a raid of a gambling house in the 1940s. **At upper left** is Mike Elliott, whose campaign for Multnomah County sheriff would be financed by gambling racketeers. (Oregonian archive)

([source](https://www.oregonlive.com/history/2017/05/where_were_downtown_portlands.html))

Why is it "at upper left"? I thought it is idiomatic to use the preposition **on** and with the definite article, "on the upper left". Is **at upper left** correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, preposition usage is tricky. My first thought was

> ***In the*** upper left is Mike Elliott...

However, any of *in, on,* or *at* seem acceptable to me in this example. For example, it's possible to say *at the left, at the top, etc*. I believe the definite article is required in typical speech and writing, just as you suspected. In other words, *at the upper left* sounds better to me than *at upper left*. I think the reason the author omitted the definite article was due to [*headlinese*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese):

> Forms of the verb "to be" and articles (a, an, the) are usually omitted.

Notice that the first "sentence" is also in headlinese.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to a *plain page with clear corners* especially on the web, *at* is **also** used. That's why you may hear *'at the bottom of the page,' 'at the left corner,'* and so on.

The definite article is not used because it merely tells the direction and not the place. That said: `'...at upper left is Mike...'` **but** `'...at the upper left corner, there is Mike...'`